# I have a problem with fabric and crashlytics when building my Android App

Tags: android, crashlytics

This is the error I am seeing.

> Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@1711854a] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

Comment: You are probably using a fairly old version of Gradle. I'd recommend upgrading

Comment: Which version of Gradle you are using ?

Answer (score 8):

For me this happened after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2 which come along with Gradle 4.6. So i switched back from

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
```

for the moment.

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing the line `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+` by the latest stable Fabric version which is 1.25.4. at the moment: `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4`

Comment: worked for me too, but current stable is `1.26.0` :)

Answer (score 7):

The cause of the issue seems incompatibility Fabric version with latest version of Gradle.The below works for me. Don't upgrade your Gradle version, Stick with your previous version and Sync the project once.

My Android Studio Version is 3.2

**project.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problem when I updated my Android studio from 3.1.4 to 3.2.

The way I got the solution. I changed in the Build.gradle (app).

from

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there's some type of conflict between io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0, and Gradle 4.6. So I found the best solution, rather than roll back io.fabric.tools:gradle, seems to be to upgrade Gradle to the latest version, 4.10.2. Seemed to work for my project without issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me this happened after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2 which come along with Gradle 4.6. So i switched back to gradle 4.4 for the moment. Maybe a bug.